# Calling activity on the G+ app

Tags: android, android-activity, google-plus

I would like to call directly an activity from the Google Plus Android app. More specifically, an activity opening a Chat+ conversation already existing. The final goal is to have a widget with a direct shortcut on a specific conversation.
I know one can open the Chat+ app, but what about a conversation? I do not ask to get a list of conversations, etc, but to access directly one. Does the Chat+ app provide such possibility?

More generally, how can we see the activities an app provide? Is there a doc somewhere for Google's Android applications?

Comment: Pretty short list, nothing G+ related.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: I guess that's where it is supposed to be, but there is almost nothing... "Note that this list is not comprehensive." =/.

Comment: [openintents.org](http://www.openintents.org) didnt have anything that sounds relevant either. 

[google+ api](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/) - This looks good but looking at the API, just has methods for basically signing in and +1'ing stuff, no mention of chat that i saw.

Comment: Openintents is an interesting link, but sadly also with a poor database. I've thought of using the API, but it is not what I am looking for (their app is neat and I don't want to rewrite it!), and as you say there is no interaction with Chat+ nor is there "write" possibilities.